# Is there a library for displaying Timezone in a selectOneMenu

Tags: java, jsf-2, timezone, selectonemenu

Currently, in my application, I use the following snippet to instantiate a timezone list for displaying in a `selectOneMenu`:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class MrBean {
    private String[] timezoneIDs;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.timezoneIDs = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
    }
}
```

The good thing that I **need & get** from this list is the `Olson` timezone ID that I can easily use with the `Joda-Time` library. However, the list is very long, which consists of all the available Timezones there are in Java. In short, it's not **user-friendly**.

[image]

In the beginning, I'd like to display a list of `GMT` timezones but I have no idea, for instance, what the corresponding Olson Timezone ID for `GMT+3` is. As a consequence, I couldn't come up with a list of `selectItems` for the `selectOneMenu`. That's the reason why I had to use `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();`.

I'd be very grateful if you could suggest a library that can help me populate the Timezone list with `GMT` labels and Olson Timezone ID values.

Comment: Can't you just use JodaTime's `DateTimeZone#getAvailableIDs()` instead? Or maybe filter out strings matching pattern `\w/\w`?

Comment: @BalusC: Still, the list would consists of too many zones. I'd like to have something like Microsoft's Timezone setting, where there are a much shorter list of `GMT+X.XX`. I think it'd be much more intuitive that way :(, isn't it?

Comment: @BalusC: Besides, for example, in China, there are so many cities. It would be much easier for users (considering a non-techie ones) to look for their `GMT` timezone than to find out, for instance, `Asia/Shanghai` is their timezone ID.

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this article](http://n.exts.ch/2012/03/timezone_pickers) of interest.

In short - the best time zone picker is none at all.  But second to that are map-based pickers.

My favorite time zone picker for JavaScript is [this one](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker).

I don't know if there is anything similar for Java or not.  A quick search turned up nothing.  If anyone knows of a good map-based time zone picker control/widget for Java, please post a link. Thanks.

Comment: :) Selecting timezone on a map looks cool. However, I'm 999% sure that my boss would reject it because that thing is not easy for an average user to use :P... Besides, earlier, in my app, I auto-detect user timezone using JavaScript. My boss asked me to put in a list in case some users wanna pick manually. Hence, this question is here :P

Comment: That's exactly right.  Detect the timezone when you can (using something like [jsTimeZoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect)), but allow the user to change it manually if desired - because detection is imperfect.  All I am saying is that my research has shown that map-based pickers are *easier* for users than drop-down list pickers.